# Display menu icon and text with actionViewClass=“CheckBox”

Tags: android, checkbox, menu, android-appcompat

All - I'm using the AppCompat library for my application, and I'm trying to display a menu item with actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox"

I'd like the title and icon to display on the bar, so I'm using the following code:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/selectall"
    android:title="Select All"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="true"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
```

but the title isn't displaying. Any ideas how to get the title to display?

Comment: try using `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` instead of `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`

Comment: not working that tooo

Comment: removing `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox"` should work. Try it out

Comment: nope, without using that there will not be checkbox

Comment: enabling **android:checked="true"** is enough to make a menu checkable.

Comment: app:showAsAction="always|withText"